# How to choose data type for creating table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have to ingest data in hive table from hdfs but I don't know how to choose correct data type for the data mentioned below:-

1. $34740$#$Disrupt Worldwide LLC$#$40425$#$null$#$13$#$6$#$317903$#$null$#$Scott Bodily$#$+$#$null$#$10$#$0$#$1$#$0$#$disruptcentral.com$#$null$#$null$#$1$#$null$#$null$#$null$#$Scott Bodily$#$1220DB56-56D7-E411-80D6-005056A451E3$#$true$
   $34741$#$The Top Tipster Leagues Limited$#$35605$#$null$#$13$#$7$#$317902$#$null$#$AM Support Team$#$+447886 027371$#$null$#$1$#$1$#$1$#$0$#$www.toptipsterleagues.com, www.toptipsterleagues.co.uk, http://test.toptipsterleague.com$#$Jamil Johnson$#$Cheng Liem Li$#$1$#$0.70$#$1.50$#$1.30$#$Bono van Nijnatten$#$0B758BF9-F1D6-E411-80D7-005056A44C5C$#$true$

Comment: For my knowledge, what is the delimiter you have used in above datasets?

Comment: I have used multi-delimiter '$#$'.

Comment: how you are handling first and last $ character in the record?

Comment: I have to use this data in spark so $ is not a issue to handel in spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this link for different data types,

[Click here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types)

Other than all the numeric and decimal fields you can use `STRING` data type. For the numeric fields based on the range and precision you can use `INT` or `DECIMAL`.

Using string and varchar or any other string data types will read null in your data as string i.e "`null`" for handling nul you should mention the table properties like below,

```
ALTER TABLE tablename SET  
SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = 'null');
```

Let me know if anything needed on this.

Comment: when I sholud use varchar,string and char beacuse here in some columns there are data as well as null but when I am trying to use varchar for that column its giving me correct result but getting null as "null" (which is double quoted) how I can remove this (double quoted) "null" to null.

Comment: using varchar and string is fine but it reads null as string like "null". check my updated answer.

Comment: I tried above command "ALTER TABLE tablename SET  
SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = 'null'); " But getting error.